# Neo4j API explanation for Python

Tags: python, neo4j

Does anybody knows where can I find a document of the Neo4j API for Python?

I'm newbie and I'm looking for a document with the list of methods and properties and the explanation of each one, or something similar.

I'm using the Neo4j Community Edition (well in fact I'm using the embedded Neo4j database in Python).

At same time I'm trying to use neoclipse to see the graph,... but sometimes the graph don't reflect the changes that I've made.

Comment: You might rerun neoclipse using the little play/stop icon to reread the graph. Otherwise have you looked at the Neo4j Manual wrt the Python integration? (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/python-embedded.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've found myself in a similar situation, and after reading the source code of python-embedded in [github](https://github.com/neo4j/python-embedded), I did realize that in the examples that they show, it's almost everything that you could make in a  different way from python, if you take a look to the code, they are just light wrappers to be able to use neo4j in a more "pythonic" manner and lifting all the burden that represent to connect to the java classes, but in the long run, if you want to get all the information, you need to read some of javadocs of the native api. In my impression this is one of those projects that you contribute more documentation and code, not look for something more.

By the way the new release 1.6 is already on github, which include a convenient wrapper to use cypher from python-embedded `GraphDatabase.query`, not just indexes and traversals.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the latest version of neo4j can be found here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/

Docs on the python bindings specifically can be found here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/python-embedded.html

Comment: Thanks, I've found this documentation previouly, where it explains some of the main methods and properties (that is good to have a little test), but I miss a list of all methods and properties with the explanation of each one.